# on() won't fire but everything else does?

Tags: jquery

I have a div **"#container1"** that contains a bunch of others that all animate when **#container1** is clicked. However in order to stop the user being able to do this twice, I have used **.off("click")** to deactivate **#container1**.

There is also a div called **"#close1"** that when clicked animates all the divs again but in the opposite direction. I would then like to use **.on("click")** to make **"#container1"** work again.

The problem is, everything else in **function close1()** works apart from **.on("click")**. Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
function open1() {
    $(this).children(".teamIconBG1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).children(".teamIcon1").stop(true, true).animate({
        "left": "-=25",
            "top": "-=25",
            "width": "190px",
            "height": "190px",
            "border-radius": "110px"
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
    $(this).children(".teamIconArrow1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconArrow1", "teamIconArrow1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).children(".teamIconTitle1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconTitle1", "teamIconTitle1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).children(".close1").stop(true, true).switchClass("close1", "close1_active", 500, "easeOutElastic");
    $(this).off("click");
}

function close1() {
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").on('click');
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconBG1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIcon1").stop(true, true).animate({
        "left": "+=25",
            "top": "+=25",
            "width": "140px",
            "height": "140px",
            "border-radius": "85px"
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconArrow1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconArrow1_active", "teamIconArrow1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconTitle1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconTitle1_active", "teamIconTitle1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".close1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("close1_active", "close1", 500, "easeOutElastic");

}

$("#container1").click(open1);
$("#container1").click(function () {
    $(".teamContent1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamContent1", "teamContent1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
});

$("#close1").click(close1);
$("#close1").click(function () {
    $(".teamContent1_active").stop(true, false).switchClass("teamContent1_active", "teamContent1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
});
```

Comment: You're not telling it what to do when clicked.  You need to add a function or function call.

Comment: In other words, it's not a flip switch that re-enables old event handlers that are removed with `.off()`. If you use `.off()` the handlers are discarded permanently.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong function. What can I use to 'turn off' the function **open1()** and 'turn on' again when I click **"#close1"**

Comment: Re-bind it (`.on('click', open1)`) just like the answers tell you to.

Comment: The problem with **.on('click', open1)** is that it actually executes the function **open1**, which is not what I would like. I only want to make the function available again when **#container1** is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use .one() to register once only handlers
2. Use namespaces for safety when you de-register handlers
3. Just calling `$(this).parent(".iconContainer1").on('click');` will not register the handler, use `$(this).parent(".iconContainer1").off('click.open').one('click', open1);` instead

Try

```
function open1() {
    $(this).children(".teamIconBG1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).children(".teamIcon1").stop(true, true).animate({
        "left": "-=25",
            "top": "-=25",
            "width": "190px",
            "height": "190px",
            "border-radius": "110px"
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
    $(this).children(".teamIconArrow1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconArrow1", "teamIconArrow1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).children(".teamIconTitle1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconTitle1", "teamIconTitle1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).children(".close1").stop(true, true).switchClass("close1", "close1_active", 500, "easeOutElastic");
}

function close1() {
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").off('click.open').one('click', open1);
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconBG1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIcon1").stop(true, true).animate({
        "left": "+=25",
            "top": "+=25",
            "width": "140px",
            "height": "140px",
            "border-radius": "85px"
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic');
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconArrow1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconArrow1_active", "teamIconArrow1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".teamIconTitle1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamIconTitle1_active", "teamIconTitle1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
    $(this).parent(".iconContainer1").children(".close1_active").stop(true, true).switchClass("close1_active", "close1", 500, "easeOutElastic");

}

$("#container1").one('click.open', open1);
$("#container1").click(function () {
    $(".teamContent1").stop(true, true).switchClass("teamContent1", "teamContent1_active", 500, "easeOutQuart");
});

$("#close1").click(close1);
$("#close1").click(function () {
    $(".teamContent1_active").stop(true, false).switchClass("teamContent1_active", "teamContent1", 500, "easeOutQuart");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont have event handler for `click`, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used like:

```
$(this).parent(".iconContainer1").on('click', function() {
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this...

```
$(this).parent(".iconContainer1").on('click', functionName);
```

or

```
$(this).parent(".iconContainer1").on('click', function() {
    // do something here when clicked
});
```

See the jQuery documention for `on()`...

http://api.jquery.com/on/